# i want replace special strings in a file with perl

Tags: regex, perl

I use this command for simple strings in lunux server

```
perl -pi -e 's/oldstring/newstring/' mosi.php
```

but i want replace this code :

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?=token2();?>" />
```

with this code in the same file :

```
<input type="hidden" name="<?=rrobot();?>" value="<?=mrobot();?>"/><input type="hidden" name="<?=trobot();?>" value="<?=rtoken();?>"/>
```

But I do not know what to do

please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with creating a regex that matches the lines you want to change:

```
perl -n -e '/PATTERN/&&print' mosi.php
```

In your case:

```
perl -n -e '/<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<\?=token2\(\);\?>" \/>/&&print' mosi.php
```

Now, add capture parentheses:

```
perl -n -e 'print "$_\n"for /(<input type="hidden" name=")token(" value=")<\?=token2\(\);\?>(" \/>)/' mosi.php
```

Now that you can collect the parts, put them together for the result:

```
perl -p -e 's/(<input type="hidden" name=")token(" value=")<\?=token2\(\);\?>(" \/>)/$1<?=rrobot();?>$2<?=mrobot();?>$3$1<?=trobot();?>$2<?=rtoken();?>$3/' mosi.php
```

And once you're absolutely sure it is correct, change the file:

```
perl -pi -e 's/(<input type="hidden" name=")token(" value=")<\?=token2\(\);\?>(" \/>)/$1<?=rrobot();?>$2<?=mrobot();?>$3$1<?=trobot();?>$2<?=rtoken();?>$3/' mosi.php
```